# Best practices and code for generating booking reference number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design, ruby-on-rails-6

I would like to generate booking reference numbers so they can easily be communicated by voice, written down, texted etc.

I currently use uuid, which works well, but results in poor UX, as strings like `510632cc-3aa4-41c2-8bd0-cbd2bd671ef4` are difficult to communicate.

Here is an Airbnb booking reference, which is nice and short and easy to communicate verbally:

[image]

#### Best practices

I gave it some thought and decided on using all capital letters except `O` (and no lower case letters), and the numbers 1-9.

This results in 25 + 9 = 34 possible characters. There could therefore be

- 34^6 = 1544804416 (1.5 billion) 6-character codes
- Or if that isn't enough, 34^7 = 52523350144 (52 billion) 7-character codes

In my use case 6-characters is ample.

To summarise, the `booking_reference` should be a random string of letters A-Z except O, and numbers 1 -9 (not 0), no lower case letters. And the column must be unique - no duplicate strings.

#### Question

Have I encapsulated best practices in my ideas above, and, presuming I create a `booking_reference` column to store the string, how can I generate these in the `bookings#create` controller action?

Note: I'm not sure if it's relevant to the ruby tag; please feel free to remove that tag if it isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this in your controller.

This example below will generate a 8-character booking reference before creating your record, no zeros and Os. Note that it doesn't look for collisions, you should elaborate on that if you expect a lot of records, there are many different ways to do it including model validations and so on. You might also want to add an index on booking_reference to your table.

```
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  before_create :generate_booking_reference
  def generate_booking_reference
    self.booking_reference = 8.times.map { [*'1'..'9', *'a'..'n', *'p'..'w'].sample }.join
    # TODO check for collisions
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: What is a full-proof way to ensure there is no duplication of generated code?

Comment: An option would be to generate the reference within a while loop that checks for no other records to use it, and only assign after exiting the loop. There should also be validations and exception handling, there are still things that can move sideways on you in production.

Comment: There should be `uniqe` DB constraint on the column to ensure that the solution you propose doesn't end up with a duplicate booking code.

Comment: @Amit Patel, definitely. He can post a different question or look at existing answers that address this aspect.